# Adding clear and undo Jbutton to java Drawing Program

Tags: java, graphics

i have hit a a snag with my project.
using the code i received from a previous question i have reproduced my problem.
i need to add a clear and undo JButton. as you can see i have added the buttons hpwever i cannot preform the desired actions.
i have tried adding ActionListeners to the class where the buttons are created and then tried to do
itemsDrawn = new ArrayList<>; ( for clear )
itemsDrawn.remove(itemsDrawn.size()-1) ( for undo )
as the resulting actions but the program locks up.

basically am i doing this right / where do i put the ActionListeners?

any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.LinearGradientPaint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class MyPaint {

    static ArrayList<Drawable> itemsDrawn;
    static JButton Clear,Undo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyPaint();
    }

    public MyPaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java 2D Drawing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

                DrawablePane dp = new DrawablePane();
                ControlPane cp = new ControlPane(dp);

                frame.add(dp);
                frame.add(cp, BorderLayout.NORTH);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class State {

        private final Color foreground;
        private final Color background;
        private final boolean gradient;
        private final boolean filled;
        private final boolean dashed;
        private int LineWidth, DashLength;

        public State(Color foreground, Color background, boolean gradient, boolean filled, boolean dashed,int LineWidth, int DashLength) {
            this.foreground = foreground;
            this.background = background;
            this.gradient = gradient;
            this.filled = filled;
            this.dashed = dashed;
            this.LineWidth = LineWidth;
            this.DashLength = DashLength;

        }

        public Color getBackground() {
            return background;
        }

        public Color getForeground() {
            return foreground;
        }

        public boolean isGradient() {
            return gradient;
        }
        public boolean isFilled() {
            return filled;
        }
        public boolean isDashed(){
            return dashed;
        }
        public int getLineWidth(){
                return LineWidth;
        }
        public int getDashLength(){
            return DashLength;
        }

    }

    public class ControlPane extends JPanel {

        private JComboBox shapes;
        private JLabel foreground;
        private JLabel background;
        private JCheckBox gradient,Filled,dashed;
        private JTextField Dashlength,Linewidth;
        private JLabel Len,Wid;


        private DrawablePane drawablePane;

        public ControlPane(DrawablePane pane) {

            shapes = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Rectangle", "Oval","Line"});
            foreground = createColorLable(Color.BLACK);
            foreground.setToolTipText("Foreground");
            background = createColorLable(Color.WHITE);
            background.setToolTipText("Background");
            gradient = new JCheckBox("Gradient");
            Filled = new JCheckBox("Filled");
            dashed = new JCheckBox("Dashed");
            Dashlength = new JTextField("1");
            Linewidth = new JTextField("1");
            Len = new JLabel("Dash Length:");
            Wid = new JLabel("Line Width:");
            Clear = new JButton("Clear");
            Undo = new JButton("Undo");






            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(Clear);
            panel.add(Undo);
            panel.add(foreground);
            panel.add(background);
            panel.add(Filled);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;

            add(shapes, gbc);
            add(panel, gbc);
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            add(gradient, gbc);
            add(dashed, gbc);
            add(Len);
            add(Linewidth);
            add(Wid);
            add(Dashlength);



            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 12)));

            this.drawablePane = pane;
            MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
            drawablePane.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
            drawablePane.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);


        }



                public int getDash(){
                String Length = Dashlength.getText();
                int Dash = Integer.parseInt(Length);
                return Dash;
            }
                public int getLine(){
                String LWidth = Linewidth.getText();
                int Line = Integer.parseInt(LWidth);
                return Line;
                }

        protected Drawable createDrawable() {

            Drawable drawable = null;
            State state = new State(foreground.getBackground(), background.getBackground(), gradient.isSelected(), Filled.isSelected(), dashed.isSelected(),getLine(), getDash());
            String selected = (String) shapes.getSelectedItem();
            if ("rectangle".equalsIgnoreCase(selected)) {
                drawable = new Square(state);
            } else if ("oval".equalsIgnoreCase(selected)) {
                drawable = new Circle(state);
            }
            else if ("Line".equalsIgnoreCase(selected)){
                drawable = new Line(state);
            }

            return drawable;

        }

        protected JLabel createColorLable(Color base) {
            final JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setBackground(base);
            label.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 25));
            label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(label, "Color", label.getBackground());
                    if (color != null) {
                        label.setBackground(color);
                    }
                }
            });
            return label;
        }

        public class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {

            private Drawable drawable;
            private Point clickPoint;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                drawable = createDrawable();
                drawable.setLocation(e.getPoint());
                drawablePane.addDrawable(drawable);
                clickPoint = e.getPoint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point drag = e.getPoint();
                Point start = clickPoint;

                int maxX = Math.max(drag.x, start.x);
                int maxY = Math.max(drag.y, start.y);
                int minX = Math.min(drag.x, start.x);
                int minY = Math.min(drag.y, start.y);

                int width = maxX - minX;
                int height = maxY - minY;

                drawable.setLocation(new Point(minX, minY));
                drawable.setSize(new Dimension(width, height));

                drawablePane.repaint();
            }

        }

    }

    public interface Drawable {

        public void paint(JComponent parent, Graphics2D g2d);

        public void setLocation(Point location);

        public void setSize(Dimension size);

        public State getState();

        public Rectangle getBounds();

    }

    public abstract class AbstractDrawable implements Drawable {

        private Rectangle bounds;
        private State state;

        public AbstractDrawable(State state) {
            bounds = new Rectangle();
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public State getState() {
            return state;
        }

        public abstract Shape getShape();

        @Override
        public void setLocation(Point location) {
            bounds.setLocation(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSize(Dimension size) {
            bounds.setSize(size);
        }

        @Override
        public Rectangle getBounds() {
            return bounds;
        }

        @Override
        public void paint(JComponent parent, Graphics2D g2d) {

            Shape shape = getShape();
            State state = getState();
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            final float dash1[] = {state.LineWidth};
            final BasicStroke dashed =
            new BasicStroke(state.DashLength,
                        BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                        BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER,
                        10.0f, dash1, 0.0f);

            if (bounds.width > 0 && bounds.height > 0) {
                 if (state.isGradient()){
                     if (state.isDashed()){
                     Point2D startPoint = new Point2D.Double(bounds.x, bounds.y);
            Point2D endPoint = new Point2D.Double(bounds.x + bounds.width, bounds.y + bounds.height);
            LinearGradientPaint gp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                            startPoint,
                            endPoint,
                            new float[]{0f, 1f},
                            new Color[]{state.getForeground(), state.getBackground()});    
                    g2d.setPaint(gp);
                    g2d.setStroke(dashed);
                    g2d.draw(shape);
                }
                     else{
            Point2D startPoint = new Point2D.Double(bounds.x, bounds.y);
            Point2D endPoint = new Point2D.Double(bounds.x + bounds.width, bounds.y + bounds.height);
            LinearGradientPaint gp = new LinearGradientPaint(
                            startPoint,
                            endPoint,
                            new float[]{0f, 1f},
                            new Color[]{state.getForeground(), state.getBackground()});
                     g2d.setPaint(gp);
                     g2d.fill(shape);
                     }
                 }

            else if (state.isFilled()){
                if (bounds.width > 0 && bounds.height > 0) {

                g2d.setPaint(state.getForeground());
                g2d.fill(shape);


                }
                }
            else if(state.isDashed()){
                g2d.setStroke(dashed);
                g2d.setPaint(state.getForeground());
                g2d.draw(shape);

            } 
            else{
                 BasicStroke stroke = new BasicStroke();
                 g2d.setStroke(stroke);
                g2d.setPaint(state.getForeground());
                g2d.draw(shape);
            }
        }
        }
        }


    public class Square extends AbstractDrawable {

        public Square(State state) {
            super(state);
        }

        @Override
        public Shape getShape() {
            return getBounds();
        }

    }

    public class Circle extends AbstractDrawable {

        public Circle(State state) {
            super(state);
        }

        @Override
        public Shape getShape() {
            Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
            return new Ellipse2D.Float(bounds.x, bounds.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        }

    }

    public class Line extends AbstractDrawable {

        public Line(State state){
            super(state);
        }
        @Override
        public Shape getShape() {
           Rectangle bounds = getBounds();
           return new Line2D.Float(bounds.x, bounds.y,bounds.width, bounds.height);

        }
    }

    public class DrawablePane extends JPanel {

        List<Drawable> itemsDrawn;

        public DrawablePane() {
            itemsDrawn =  new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Drawable d : itemsDrawn) {
                d.paint(this, g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void addDrawable(Drawable drawable) {

            itemsDrawn.add(drawable);
            repaint();

        }



               }
           }
```

this is the ControlPane class with the implemented Undo and Clear Buttons

```
public ControlPane(DrawablePane pane) {

            shapes = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Rectangle", "Oval","Line"});
            foreground = createColorLable(Color.BLACK);
            foreground.setToolTipText("Foreground");
            background = createColorLable(Color.WHITE);
            background.setToolTipText("Background");
            gradient = new JCheckBox("Gradient");
            Filled = new JCheckBox("Filled");
            dashed = new JCheckBox("Dashed");
            Dashlength = new JTextField("1");
            Linewidth = new JTextField("1");
            Len = new JLabel("Dash Length:");
            Wid = new JLabel("Line Width:");
            Clear = new JButton("Clear");
            Undo = new JButton("Undo");






            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(Clear);
            panel.add(Undo);
            panel.add(foreground);
            panel.add(background);
            panel.add(Filled);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.weightx = 1;

            add(shapes, gbc);
            add(panel, gbc);
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            add(gradient, gbc);
            add(dashed, gbc);
            add(Len);
            add(Linewidth);
            add(Wid);
            add(Dashlength);



            setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK), new EmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 12)));

            this.drawablePane = pane;
            MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
            drawablePane.addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
            drawablePane.addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);

            Clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               itemsDrawn = new ArrayList<>();
               (Not sure what to use here).repaint();
           }
       });
            undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               if (itemsDrawn.size() != 0) {
                   itemsDrawn.remove(itemsDrawn.size() - 1);
                   (Not sure what to put here).repaint();
               }
           }
       });

        }
```

so something like this ( clear and undo methods in DrawablePane )

```
Clear.addActionListner(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                    Clear();
                }
            });

          Undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               Undo();
           }
       });
public class DrawablePane extends JPanel {

        List<Drawable> itemsDrawn;

        public DrawablePane() {
            itemsDrawn =  new ArrayList<>();

        }
        public void undo(){
            if (itemsDrawn.size() != 0) {
                   itemsDrawn.remove(itemsDrawn.size() - 1);
                   repaint();
        }
        }
        public void Clear(){
             itemsDrawn = new ArrayList<>();
               repaint();

        }
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            for (Drawable d : itemsDrawn) {
                d.paint(this, g2d);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        public void addDrawable(Drawable drawable) {

            itemsDrawn.add(drawable);
            repaint();

        }



               }
           }
```

i am getting an error saying Clear and Undo cannot be found in DrawablePane

Comment: That is a lot of code for someone to read, perhaps the specific error / line of code giving you a problem will get you more help..

Comment: Do your drawing on a BufferedImage and display it in your DrawPane's `paintComponent` method. When you want to clear it, simply cover the BufferedImage with a background color or create a new BufferedImage and stuff it into the image variable.

Comment: Where's the implementation of undo and clear?

Comment: i added the whole code because im not sure where if im adding the action listeners in the correct spot. if i am wrong then i was hoping someone could point out where they need to be.

Comment: madProgrammer- i had them in the ControlPane class but they broke the code. ill add the class with them implemented now

Comment: i have added the code for the actionListeners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is `itemsDrawn` is used by the `DrawablePane` not the `ControlPane`, so trying to change it from `ControlPane` will have no effect on `DrawablePane`.

Instead, you should add two methods to `DrawablePane` called, `undo` and `clear`, which can be called from your `ActionListener`s in `ControlPane`

**Updated with example**

First, add an `undo` and `clear` method to the `DrawablePane`...

```
public class DrawablePane extends JPanel {

    List<Drawable> itemsDrawn;

    public DrawablePane() {
        itemsDrawn = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        for (Drawable d : itemsDrawn) {
            d.paint(this, g2d);
        }
        g2d.dispose();
    }

    public void addDrawable(Drawable drawable) {

        itemsDrawn.add(drawable);
        repaint();

    }

    public void undo() {

        if (!itemsDrawn.isEmpty()) {

            int size = itemsDrawn.size() - 1;
            itemsDrawn.remove(size);
            repaint();

        }

    }

    public void clear() {

        itemsDrawn.clear();
        repaint();

    }

}
```

Second, call the methods from the appropriate `ActionListener`...

```
clear.addActionListner(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPreformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        drawablePane.clear();
    }
});

undo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        drawablePane.undo();
    }
});
```

These would, obviously, be created in your `ControlPane`

Comment: i tried adding the methods but i cant call them from ControlPane
also what do i call repaint on?
i have added the code to my original post

Comment: im getting an error saying undo and clear cannot be found in DrawingPane

Comment: *"you should add two methods"*

Comment: i just cant call them from actionPreformed

Comment: Thank you. i dont understand what you did differently to be able to access drawablePane but it worked.. i tried for over an hour and kept getting the same error.

Comment: actually i just realized i was using DrawablePane.Clear(); instead of drawablePane.Clear().......

Comment: Variable names in Java should start with a lower case in order to distinguish them from class names ... as a convention ... and professional Java developers are picky about their conventions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do your drawing on a BufferedImage and display it in your DrawPane's paintComponent method. When you want to clear it, simply cover the BufferedImage with a background color or create a new BufferedImage and stuff it into the image variable.

```
public class DrawablePane extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    List<Drawable> itemsDrawn;

    public DrawablePane() {
        itemsDrawn =  new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
           g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }
     }

     public void addDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        itemsDrawn.add(drawable);
        repaint();
     }

     public void clear() {
       img = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
       repaint();
     }

}
```

Do all your drawing **on** the BufferedImage in public methods that you give this class.

Comment: It would still equate to essentially the same thing. To do an undo, you'd have to clear the buffer and reproduce the result up to but not including the last command. Then you also have the added issue the container changing size. Not saying its a bad idea, just saying ;)

Comment: this is a good idea but as mad programmer mentioned the changes to the container size kinda screw me along with adding the undo option

Comment: @Lewmor71: the change in size of course can be kludge-fixed with either 1) a WindowListener, and create a new BI if the window resizes, or 2) using a BI that's larger than the JPanel and "big enough" to handle most resizes.

Comment: i get the same error here.. i am unable to call clear in the ActionListener